# How to find the system impact of a query in postgres

Tags: postgresql

When an query is executed in postgres - pgadmin4 .
Can i know the query to check the performance of the query using any system tables ?

example :

1. Time taken
2. Query run by 
   3.CPU impact
3. any blocks
   etc..

Answer (score 1):

Add pg_stat_statements in shared preload libraries 
Create extension pg_stat_statements. 
Then query on pg_stat_statements to get time related stats of the query.

Query run by can be tracked from pg_stat_activity for the currently running statements.

For blocks you can query  as below 
SELECT
    activity.pid,
    activity.usename,
    activity.query,
    blocking.pid AS blocking_id,
    blocking.query AS blocking_query
FROM pg_stat_activity AS activity
JOIN pg_stat_activity AS blocking ON blocking.pid = ANY(pg_blocking_pids(activity.pid));